# Nexus (10): how to reset/debug usb when not recognized by windows or mac anymore

Tags: android, debugging, usb, nexus-10

I was happily developing my Android app and debugging it on my Nexus 10 the other day. Next morning the Nexus 10 wasn't recognized anymore.

It shows its charging but no info about USB-Debugging or Connected as Media Device in the upper left corner.

I tried different PCs, Macs, USB-Cables, uninstalled the Nexus 10 driver, did a system cache wipe on the Nexus 10 (in recovery boot).
A fresh Win7 PC (never seen a Nexus 10) doesn't even try to find a driver for it.

I tried to connect (with the same cable and PCs/Macs) a Galaxy S4 and everything (media device, usb debugging) works perfect.

Of course I tried to enable/disable (USB) Debugging and all the storage variants (MTP and PTP) the Nexus 10 offers. Nothing on the PC/Mac side happens.

Is there a way to debug or log somehow into a file what the Nexus 10 is doing when I connect the USB cable? Can I write a simple app which debugs/listen to what happens on the USB port?

Thanks
Soko

Comment: Not sure about your case but I use Linux and sometime when it does not recognize device I just kill and restart adb server and it works fine then. Command "./abd kill-server" followed by "./abd start-server". (Keep your device connected while restarting adb server)

Comment: I read about that. The problem is though a standard pc doesn't even recognize it anymore. No Android environment installed